# Python auto-create unique lists during runtime

Tags: python, list

Im writing a program and I've run into an issue where I need the program to create lists on its own.

```
animals = ["cat", "dog", "rat", "horse"]
```

For example. Then, I want a function that list.appends list.

```
def append()
    input = input(">>>")
    animals.append(input)
```

When it does this, I want it to make a new list for the user input that is entered. Is there anyway to do this without having to use file functions?

The ultimate goal is for this function to:

- Append the list "animals" (Got that part)
- Then, I want it to create a new list that is unique to the input. The list might be referred to by the user input if at all possible.
- Lastly, I want this list to be editable by the user Which is easy with list.append. But I need to somehow then be able to refer to this unique list in order to do that.

Hope that clears up some confusion.

Comment: You seem to have the idea down, make an empty list and append the user's input to the list, what's the problem?

Comment: "create lists on its own"? Are you wanting someone to input a list (a line at a time maybe?) - if so - you're nearly there...

Comment: Yes, that part I can do, easy, The issue is in having the program create said empty list that can be edited by the user

Comment: @root I want to append the list "animals" and I want the program to create a unique list that the user can edit. So the list "animals will be like a main list that each term in it has it's own list. I don't want to code all of these myself though, so I want the program to make them for me. Edited question for clarity.

Comment: What about my question is so wrong as to make me receive a downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood where you are aiming at. I suggest you use a `dict` of `lists`:

```
animals = {}
while True:
    print(', '.join(i for i in animals))
    animal = input('Choose an animal, or pick a newe one: ')
    if animal == "":
        break
    item = input('enter item: ')    
    animals.setdefault(animal,[]).append(item)

print(animals)

Choose an animal, or pick a newe one: rat
enter item: foo
rat
Choose an animal, or pick a newe one: dog
enter item: bar
rat, dog
Choose an animal, or pick a newe one: 
{'rat': ['foo'], 'dog': ['bar']}
```

Comment: This looks promising, I have one question about this part: print('options are: '+', '.join(i for i in animals)) What does this part do? (Or tell the user to do?)

Comment: this prints all the animal names in the dict

Comment: And then when the user inputs one of the items in the list "animals" It will allow them to append that list?

Comment: @cbbcbail Why don't you run it, and see what it does? :) You could put in some print statements to help you debug if needed.

Comment: @Alex L I realize I look stupid now thanks for pointing that out. But yes I did run it. I Just need to add a list.count to stop it from attempting to edit lists that don't exist. Lol.

Comment: @cbbcbail No worries. For validation you could do something nice like `if animal not in animals.keys(): print "Invalid selection"; continue`

Comment: Good, point I was doing the more convoluted: if list.count =! 0

Comment: @cbbcbail:now it lets you create new animals if you want. If you just hit enter without entering an animal,the loop will break and the dict will be printed.

Comment: Thanks, but not necessary. Sorry, But I got all that i need thanks for your help and comments so I could help you understand the question :)